# Program never gets past the >>. that was overloaded

Tags: c++, arrays, operator-overloading

I am building a class called `nim`, that contains large integer numbers. The header of my class looks like this:

```
#ifndef NUMAR_INTREG_MARE_H_INCLUDED
#define NUMAR_INTREG_MARE_H_INCLUDED
#include "array.h"
#include <iostream>
class nim///nim=numar_intreg_mare
{
    Array a;//the large integer number
    int semn;//the sign of the number
    int n;//the length of the number
public:
    nim();
    nim(nim const &ob);
    ~nim();
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const nim& ob);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, nim& ob);
};


#endif // NUMAR_INTREG_MARE_H_INCLUDED
```

As you can see, it has an attribute of type `Array`, which is another class I build. The header for `Array` is:

```
#ifndef ARRAY_H_INCLUDED
#define ARRAY_H_INCLUDED
#include <iostream>
class Array{
private:
    int* c;
    int len, capacity;
public:
    Array();
    void Append(int);
    ~Array();
    int& operator[] (int) const;
    void Afisare();//outputiing the array
    friend class nim;
};

#endif // ARRAY_H_INCLUDED
```

I built this class so that I can have dynamically allocated memory, as you can see from how `Append` works:

```
#include "array.h"
#include <iostream>
 Array::Array()
    {
        capacity=1;
        c=new int[capacity];
        len=0;
    }
void Array::Append(int x)
    {
        int* temp;
        if(len>=capacity)
        {
            temp=new int[2*capacity];
            for(int i=0; i<capacity; i++)
            {
                temp[i]=c[i];
            }
            capacity*=2;
            delete[] c;
            c=temp;
        }
        c[len]=x;
        len++;
    }
Array::~Array()
    {
            delete[]c;
    }

int& Array::operator[] (int x) const
    {
        return c[x];
    }
void Array::Afisare()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
            std::cout<<c[i]<<" ";
        std::cout<<"\n";
    }
```

Going back to my original `nim` class, this is how I implemented the functions:

```
#include "numar_intreg_mare.h"
#include <iostream>
nim::nim() : semn(0)
{
    Array a;
}
nim::nim(nim const &ob) : a(ob.a), semn(ob.semn), n(ob.n){}
nim::~nim(){}
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &os, const nim &ob)
{
    if(ob.semn==-1) os<<"-";
    else if(ob.semn==1) os<<"+";
    for(int i=0; i<ob.n; i++)
    {
        os<<ob.a[i];
    }
    os<<"\n";
    return os;
}
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, nim &ob)
{
    std::cout<<"n=";
    int n, semn;
    is>>n;
    ob.n=n;
    std::cout<<"semn=";
    is>>semn;
    ob.semn=semn;
    std::cout<<"a=";
    for(int j = 0; j < ob.n; j++)
        is >> ob.a[j];
    return is;
}
```

Now, when my `main.cpp` looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "array.h"
#include "numar_intreg_mare.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    nim nr;
    cin>>nr;
    cout<<"gets past cin";
    cout<<nr;
    return 0;
}
```

My program never outputs "gets past cin" so.. it doesn't get past `cin`. The problem is that it doesn't read character by character and I have to be careful to always press enter after a character. Does anyone know how to make it read character by character?

Comment: You never use `Array::Append()` function, so length of `ob.a.c` array in `operator >>` is always equal to 1.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but it's bad form to have output in an input operator.

Comment: You also read from `std::cin` for some input, not the stream that was passed as argument.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen It's for my OOP course, we're not allowed to use templates for now.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude How do I input from istream?

Comment: You already do it in the loop.

Comment: @TedLyngmo it never gets out of the for loop apparently

Comment: No, but how far into the `operator>>` function does it come? You should be able to find the exact line by just looking in the debugger or printing out something between all the lines.

Comment: @TedLyngmo it's not reading character by character and that's what got me confused

Comment: You have many lines doing `is >> variable;` is it stopping at the first one?

Comment: Btw, you assign a value to `nim::n` but that doesn't change the `Array`s capacity which stays at `1` as @Yksisarvinen mentioned.

Comment: @TedLyngmo it does stop at the first one. I fixed the capacity, thank you.

Comment: So, it prints `n=` and you enter an integer and press return, but it never prints `semn=`? Btw, you should put the updated code in the question as your current code will have UB if one enters an `n` that is larger than 1.

Comment: Note that you only implement a destructor & copy constructor for `nim`, and a destructor for `Array`. Thus you're missing 7 other functions. See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three.